# Error when using gdal_calc.py

Tags: python, gdal, command-line

I'm trying to perform some raster calculations (ex:`A+B`, `A*(A>0)`) using `gdal_calc.py`, but I'm stuck with an error when I try to make this simple test command:

```
import subprocess
import sys

subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\GDAL\\gdal_calc.py', '-A', 'd:\\mnt_5x5.tif', '--outfile=d:\\test.tif', '--calc="A+1" '])
```

When I run it in CMD, it gives the following error:

```
0 ..
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\PROGRA~2\GDAL\gdal_calc.py", line 329, in <module>
    main()
  File "C:\PROGRA~2\GDAL\gdal_calc.py", line 326, in main
    doit(opts, args)
  File "C:\PROGRA~2\GDAL\gdal_calc.py", line 282, in doit
    myResult = ((1*(myNDVs==0))*myResult) + (myOutNDV*myNDVs)
TypeError: ufunc 'multiply' did not contain a loop with signature matching types
 dtype('S11') dtype('S11') dtype('S11')
```

GDAL is installed properly, since I had no problems running similar scripts with `gdalwarp.exe` and `gdal_translate.exe`.
The error mentions something about the `numpy class dtype`, but I'm not very familiar with numpy syntax.

As seen [here](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/98415/error-193-while-running-gdal-calc-py-using-subprocess-call-in-python) it's an easy task, I don't know what I'm missing.

Comment: Why do you even call a python script as a subprocess?

Comment: Because I have several versions of python/GDAL installed and I need to specify which one should run the script/command.

Comment: And something like c:\python27\python gdal_calc.py will not work in your case, or?

Answer (score 11):

This seems to be a quoting issue. Try running:

`subprocess.call([sys.executable, 'C:\\PROGRA~2\\GDAL\\gdal_calc.py', '-A', 'd:\\mnt_5x5.tif', '--outfile=d:\\test.tif', '--calc=A+1'])`

The `--calc=A+1` argument needs to be quoted when run at the CLI, but doesn't need quotes when run in python using `subprocess`.

Comment: Is it possible to search 'gdal_calc.py' from 'path' of environment variable automatically?

Comment: Good question @BruceXiaolongLiu. You should be able to add the directory of gdal_calc.py to your PATH, and then call it from your command line. What operating system are you on, and where is the gdal_calc.py code now?

Comment: Actually I expect my code to be cross-platform. And I used it in the conda environment. I found out the location of `gdal_calc.py` in the conda prefix directory. So I solved it in my case with: `import os, pathlib, subprocess; gdal_calc_script = pathlib.Path(os.getenv('CONDA_EXE')).parent / 'gdal_calc.py'; command = [ sys.executable, gdal_calc_script, .......]; subprocess.run(command);`. It works in both Windows and WSL. A little trick. It won't work without conda environment.

Comment: It only works in WSL/Linux by adding the directory of `gdal_calc.py` to the PATH. **NOT** in Windows. @Charlie. I can just use `subprocess.run(['gdal_calc.py', ....])` in linux. While, it is not a win32 application in Windows. So we have to add `sys.executable` and its absolute path. It was my case.

Comment: I haven't worked much in conda @BruceXiaolongLiu, but glad it's working in WSL/LInux.

Answer (score 4):

Try to use `os` instead of `subprocess`. This worked for me:

```
import os
gdal_calc =  'python C:/PROGRA~2/GDAL/gdal_calc.py -A d:/mnt_5x5.tif --outfile=d:/test.tif --calc="A+1"'
os.system(gdal_calc)
```