# python GDAL raster calculation error message

Tags: python, gdal, python-2.7, gdal-calc

I am trying to follow [Error when using gdal_calc.py](https://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/201380) and Friend commented:

```
import os
gdal_calc =  'python C:/PROGRA~2/GDAL/gdal_calc.py -A d:/mnt_5x5.tif --outfile=d:/test.tif --calc="A+1"'
os.system(gdal_calc)
```

but I take error :

```
..<string>:1: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply
    C:/OSGeo4W64/bin/gdal_calc.py:296: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
```

here complete message :

```
0 ..<string>:1: RuntimeWarning: overflow encountered in multiply
C:/OSGeo4W64/bin/gdal_calc.py:296: RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in multiply
  myResult = ((1*(myNDVs==0))*myResult) + (myOutNDV*myNDVs)
 10 .. 20 .. 30 .. 40 .. 50 .. 60 .. 70 .. 80 .. 90 .. 100 - Done
```

Any idea why I take this error?

I take new image for output but I am not sure if this image is correct after this error .

here my complete code :

```
gdal_calc =  'python C:/OSGeo4W64/bin/gdal_calc.py -A {0} -B {1} -C {2} --outfile=test.tif --calc="(5*A)+(5*B)+(2*C)"'.format(a,b,c)
os.system(gdal_calc)
```

Comment: What is the datatype of your tiff? Check the maximum values of bands and estimate if the results from (5*A)+(5*B)+(2*C) can fit into the valid range for that datatype.

Comment: @user30184 all datatype is float32.my datasets is DEM , slope ,aspect has different maximum values

Comment: @user30184 but one dataset have different no data value that is the problem ?

Comment: Could be. Is that value some very small negative number? We know that the error is "overflow encountered in multiply".

Comment: @user30184 what value you mean ?and if you know that error where is solution ? :)

Comment: You wrote about different nodata values. I know the error because I read it from the error message. About solving the problem, I know very little about gdal_ calc.